# Adding a UILabel to a UIToolbar

Tags: ios, iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to add a label to my toolbar. Button works great, however when I add the label object, it crashes. Any ideas?

```
UIBarButtonItem *setDateRangeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set date range"
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                      target:self
                                                                      action:@selector(setDateRangeClicked:)];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 20)];
label.text = @"test";

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:setDateRangeButton,label, nil]];

// Add the toolbar as a subview to the navigation controller.
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];

// Reload the table view
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Have a look into this

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourCustomView];
```

Essentially every item must be a "button" but they can be instantiated with any view you require. Here is some example code. Note, since other buttons are typically on the toolbar, spacers are placed on each side of the title button so it stays centered.

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[self.toolbar items] mutableCopy];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[items addObject:spacer];
[spacer release];

self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0 , 11.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 21.0f)];
[self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18]];
[self.titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:157.0/255.0 green:157.0/255.0 blue:157.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[self.titleLabel setText:@"Title"];
[self.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[items addObject:spacer2];
[spacer2 release];

UIBarButtonItem *title = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.titleLabel];
[items addObject:title];
[title release];

[self.toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
[items release];
```

Comment: Note that if you chose to go this route you must style your label appropriately (label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor], etc).  You can also init a UIBarButtonItem to be styled Plain which will give you a similar look

Comment: I know this is a really old post, but I have a question about this answer. Once this is done, is there any way to access the titleLabel later to change it, or is it impossible since everything has been released?

Comment: Ryan, the UILabel probably still exists -- it's self.titleLabel.  This example needs a property declared and synthesized for UILabel *titleLabel, but that code isn't shown.  If you have access to the object (probably a UIViewController) that runs this code, you can access its titleLabel.  E.g., you could add a method on the view controller, pass in the new title you want, and then call [self.titleLabel setText:newTitle].

Comment: Wouldn't you want the second spacer added after the title button bar item?

Answer (score 121):

For those using Interface Builder to layout your `UIToolBar`, it is also possible to do this using Interface Builder alone.

To add a `UILabel` to a `UIToolBar` you need to add a generic `UIView` object to your `UIToolBar` in IB by dragging a new `UIView` object over your `UIToolBar`. `IB` will automatically create a `UIBarButtonItem` that will be initialized with your custom `UIView`. Next add a `UILabel` to the `UIView` and edit the `UILabel` graphically to match your preferred style. You can then visually set up your fixed and/or variable spacers as desired to position your `UILabel` appropriately.

You must also set the background of both the `UILabel` and the `UIView` to `clearColor` to get the `UIToolBar` to show through correctly under the `UILabel`.

Comment: Nice trick, didn’t know you can do it in Interface Builder. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a way to add a UIButton with custom image using that method? I can add a UIButton, but the image doesn't show up.

Comment: Much more sensible to do this in interface builder. Most of the time,  it's much easier to maintain a toolbar in interface builder than it is using code.

Comment: Great advice! How can I access the label programmatically? I tried to do it via the bar button's `customView` property but did get a runtime error.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.  When I drag a UIView onto the toolbar, it ends up being placed inside the view controller, not on the toolbar.  Also, do we do this in the navigation controller or in the view controller?

Comment: I simply just dragged a UILabel onto my UIToolbar and centered it.. Didn't have to drag in another view or anything. I have a UIView which contains a UIToolBar, UIPickerView, and the UILabel title

Comment: That does not seem to work. If it worked once a long time ago, not anymore in XCode 6 ...

Comment: Seems to work (Xcode 7.3.1) but when I do this Xcode gets very laggy

Comment: The same trouble - Storyboard becomes extremely slow right after adding the view into Toolbar (Xcode 7.3.1). Beware - it'll take time and patience to delete it from the Toolbar.

Comment: You should update your answer to point out that this only works with toolbars added to a view controller manually; it does not work with the toolbar that is added for you.

Comment: Great answer. Was completely unaware that it could be done through storyboard. Working like charm.

Answer (score 34):

I found answerBot's answer very useful, but I think I found an even easier way, in Interface Builder:

- create a UIBarButtonItem and add it to your Toolbar in Interface
  Builder

[image]

- Uncheck "enabled" for this BarButtonItem

[image]

- plug this BarButtonItem to a property in your class (this is in
  Swift, but would be very similar in Obj-C):

  ```
  @IBOutlet private weak var lastUpdateButton: UIBarButtonItem! // Dummy barButtonItem whose customView is lastUpdateLabel
  ```
- add another property for the Label itself:

  ```
  private var lastUpdateLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
  ```
- in viewDidLoad, add the following code to set the properties of your
  label, and add it as the customView of your BarButtonItem

  ```
  // Dummy button containing the date of last update
  lastUpdateLabel.sizeToFit()
  lastUpdateLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  lastUpdateLabel.textAlignment = .Center
  lastUpdateButton.customView = lastUpdateLabel
  ```
- To update the `UILabel` text:

  ```
  lastUpdateLabel.text = "Updated: 9/12/14, 2:53"
  lastUpdateLabel.sizeToFit()
  ```

Result :

[image]

You have to call `lastUpdateLabel.sizetoFit()` each time you update the label text

Comment: I created a UIBarButtonItem same as you, left it enabled, and superimposed a label using the following code:
  
`UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];  
label.text = @"Hello";
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
[label sizeToFit];
self.barItem.customView = label;`

Answer (score 6):

One of the things I'm using this trick for is to instantiate a `UIActivityIndicatorView` on top of the `UIToolBar`, something that otherwise wouldn't be possible. For instance here I have a `UIToolBar` with 2 `UIBarButtonItem`, a `FlexibleSpaceBarButtonItem`, and then another `UIBarButtonItem`. I want to insert a `UIActivityIndicatorView` into the `UIToolBar` between the flexible space and the final (right-hand) button. So in my `RootViewController` I do the following,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];// Add an invisible UIActivityViewIndicator to the toolbar
UIToolbar *toolbar = (UIToolbar *)[self.view viewWithTag:767];
NSArray *items = [toolbar items];

activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f)];
[activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];    

NSArray *newItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[items objectAtIndex:0],[items objectAtIndex:1],[items objectAtIndex:2],
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator], [items objectAtIndex:3],nil];
[toolbar setItems:newItems];}
```

Comment: This code leaks the memory allocated for the UIBarButtonItem with the custom activity indicator view. (It also leaks the activity indicator's memory, but I assume that's being released below the end of the code fragment.

Answer (score 4):

### Details

- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Full sample

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private weak var toolBar: UIToolbar?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var bounds =  UIScreen.main.bounds
        let bottomBarWithHeight = CGFloat(44)
        bounds.origin.y = bounds.height - bottomBarWithHeight
        bounds.size.height = bottomBarWithHeight
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: bounds)
        view.addSubview(toolBar)

        var buttons = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        buttons.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.action)))
        buttons.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .camera, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.action)))
        buttons.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil))
        buttons.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil))
        buttons.append(ToolBarTitleItem(text: "\(NSDate())", font: .systemFont(ofSize: 12), color: .lightGray))
        buttons.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil))
        buttons.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action:  #selector(ViewController.action)))
        toolBar.items = buttons

        self.toolBar = toolBar
    }
    @objc func action() { print("action") }
}

class ToolBarTitleItem: UIBarButtonItem {

    init(text: String, font: UIFont, color: UIColor) {
        let label =  UILabel(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        label.text = text
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.font = font
        label.textColor = color
        label.textAlignment = .center
        super.init()
        customView = label
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder) }
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: I like this, but what if I have TableView then it will scroll with this bar. How do I fix that?

Comment: Hello Maxim, I can’t understand your problem. Please, describe the result you want to get.

Comment: Ok, I am using UITableViewController and if I set view.addSubview(toolBar!) and scroll my tableview the bar will scroll with tableView, I want it to have a fixed bottom position

Comment: I think, you should use UIViewController with UITableView (instead UITableViewController) as a subview.

Comment: Ok spasibo. I will try that

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Matt R I used interface builder. But I wanted to have 1 `UIWebView` inside instead so that i can have some text bolded and other text not (like the mail app). So

1. Add the webview instead.
2. Uncheck opaque
3. Make sure background is clear color
4. Hook everything up with `IBOutlet`
5. Use the below `html` to have a transparent background so the toolbar shines through

Code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>body{font-size:11px;text-align:center;background-color:transparent;color:#fff;font-family:helvetica;vertical-align:middle;</style> </head><body><b>Updated</b> 10/11/12 <b>11:09</b> AM</body></html>"];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140 , 0, 50, 250)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
label.text = @"TEXT";
UIView *view = (UIView *) label;
[self.barItem setCustomView:view];
```

Note: `self.barItem` is a `UIBarButtonItem` added from the object library and placed between two flexible spaces.

another way is to remove the `[self.barItem setCustom:view]` line and change the parameters of the `label` (width) so that it fills the entire toolbar and set the alignment to middle and the font by yourself in code,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adding a view up the toolbar view you can try this:

```
[self.navigationController.tabBarController.view addSubview:yourView];
```

Answer (score 0):

could use a disabled BarButtonItem

```
let resultsLabel = UIBarButtonItem(title: "number of results", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
resultsLabel.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

**A solution to this in Swift**

One way you could do this is by creating a `UILabel` and then adding it as custom view to a `UIBarButtonItem` which you then add to the toolbar.
For example:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
        
        let textLabel = UILabel()
        textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        textLabel.text = "Text Label" // Change this to be any string you want
        let textButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: textLabel)
        let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        setToolbarItems([spacer, textButton, spacer], animated: false)
    }
    
}
```

> NOTE: The `flexibleSpace`'s position the label in the centre of the tool bar

Here's a screenshot of what this would look like:
[image: Example Screenshot]

> NOTE: Without a tab bar the toolbar would take up the bottom of the screen.