# How do I get the UIToolbar font to match UINavigation Controller?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uilabel, uitoolbar

Using [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333441/adding-a-uilabel-to-a-uitoolbar), I was able to add a UILabel to a UIToolbar, however, it looks crappy.  Anyone know how to get the text size / color / shadow to match the title for a UINavigationController?

Navigation Controller
[alt text http://www.codingwithoutcomments.com/uploads/Picture1.png](http://www.codingwithoutcomments.com/uploads/Picture1.png)

UIToolbar with UILabel
[alt text http://www.codingwithoutcomments.com/uploads/Picture2.png](http://www.codingwithoutcomments.com/uploads/Picture2.png)

What steps do I need to take to make them match?

Comment: Do you want to know the font specs of the apple UIToolBar or just how to set the font and colour of a UILabel?

Comment: I amended my question.  See changes.

Comment: I guess I wondered if someone knew the font and colour specs for a UILabel that matches the Navigation Controller font and colour specs for "Item"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might also want to add a shadow?

```
itemLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
itemLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1.0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the question is about iPhone, but in case anyone is wondering, here are the numbers for iPad:

```
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
    titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:.5f];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:113.f/255.f green:120.f/255.f blue:127.f/255.f alpha:1.f];
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.text = @"Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel * itemLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rectArea];
itemLabel.text = @"Item";   
itemLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
itemLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22.0];
```