# Can I center a UIToolbar item?

Tags: iphone, uilabel, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am putting a label on a UIToolbar (per this tip: [Adding a UILabel to a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333441/adding-a-uilabel-to-a-uitoolbar)).

But the toolbar has a button on the left side, and so flexible spaces throw the label off the center, which is where I'd like it to be. Can I somehow center this toolbar item so that it remains centered in the toolbar?

(Already tried balancing the button with a dummy fixed space, no dice.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way would be to put the label *above* the bar, in it's parent view, and justify it there.

Comment: Thanks other-Ben, that was my plan B. :)

Comment: EricS's method is superior and much easier to implement.

Comment: EricS's method is "static" and doesn't work when you change orientation

Answer (score 39):

Add a flexible space item to the left and right of your center item, like you did. Then add a fixed space item at the end and set the width to whatever the left button width is -- somewhere around 28 pixels.

```
UIBarButtonItem *fixedItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:NULL] autorelease];
fixedItem.width = 28;
```

Comment: This assumes the system font will never change (it has several times) and the user will never set a different sized font. It also ignores localizations of your button’s title being different widths.

Answer (score 6):

To center a text/title on a toolbar you can use a simple `UILabel` like see below:

```
UILabel *labelTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
labelTitle.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
labelTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
labelTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
labelTitle.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
labelTitle.text = @"Your Title";
[labelTitle sizeToFit];
CGRect labelTitleFrame = labelTitle.frame;
labelTitleFrame.size.width = self.toolbar.bounds.size.width;
labelTitleFrame.origin.y = (self.toolbar.bounds.size.height - labelTitleFrame.size.height) / 2;
labelTitle.frame = labelTitleFrame;
labelTitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
// Just add UILabel like UIToolBar's subview 
[self.toolbar addSubview:labelTitle];
[labelTitle release];
labelTitle = nil;
```

Comment: This method work properly when you change orientation and when there are left or right bar buttons

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can center a toolbar item just put two flexible space in the toolbar like :

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexibaleSpaceBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:loginButton,flexibaleSpaceBarButton,toolBarLabel,flexibaleSpaceBarButton, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you DON'T use flexible or fixed spaces, you can modify the internal UIToolbar UIStackView distribution as below. Note that you should call `toolbar.centerItemsHorizontally()` in your view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method.

```
extension UIView {
    func allSubviews() -> [UIView] {
        var _allSubviews: [UIView] = []
        for subview in self.subviews {
            _allSubviews += subview.allSubviews()
            _allSubviews.append(subview)
        }
        return _allSubviews
    }
}
extension UIToolbar {
    func centerItemsHorizontally() {
        allSubviews().forEach { subview in
            if let stackView = subview as? UIStackView {
                stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]