# iOS Static footer in Split View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, footer, uisplitviewcontroller

We're trying to add a static footer in the Root View Controller of our Split View Controller such as in the iOS Mail app:

[image]

I've seen mention ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687370/tablefooterview-property-doesnt-fix-the-footer-at-the-bottom-of-the-table-view/15687573#15687573)) of how to do this outside of a Split View Controller but haven't been able to get this to work with our Split View configuration.

How can you do this?

Comment: What did you try and what does not work?

Comment: The suggestions I've seen refer to embedding both a table view and a footer view in a parent view.  But I couldn't see how to do that using the spot view. Doesn't seem to be a way to do this on the Storyboard.

Comment: There is no difference between a `SplitView`s Master `ViewController` and a non-splitView view controller. What did you try and what is the actual issue?

Comment: Figured it out (See below).  I changed track here and instead of trying to embed views just went with the nav bar toolbar which seems to work well in testing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out with a selection of existing SO posts -

Configured the footer by [using our Navigation Controller's toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33844650/47281).  Just enabled the toolbar for the Nav Controller in our Storyboard.

Then added a label to the toolbar [using a dummy button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25808958/47281).

And centered that label [using a flexible space item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4568525/47281).