# UIButton is crashing the application

Tags: iphone

Added `UIButton` to app

```
UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(play:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"];

[playButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

when i run the application it is crashing and message is `UIButtonView unrecognized selector`

Did exception breakpoint

Found that it is crashing at

```
[toolbar setItems:toolbarItems];
```

I think i m not adding `UIButton` properly to `toolbar`

```
//Add buttons to the array

NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: settingsButton, flexItem, rewind, flexItem, playButton, flexItem, pause, flexItem, modalBarButtonItem, nil];

 [toolbar setItems:toolbarItems];
```

Anyideas to fix this one.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't directly stick a `UIButton` into a `UIToolBar`. You have to encapsulate the `UIButton` in a `UIBarButtonItem`'s view and then stick your custom `UIBarButtonItem` in the `UIToolBar`. If you don't need a custom look or functionality, you may want to look into using a standard `UIBarButtonItem` because it looks nice without much work on your part.

See [Adding a UILabel to a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333441/adding-a-uilabel-to-a-uitoolbar) for an example.

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *play = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:playButton];
    
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = play; i made these changes now app is not crashing but dont see uibutton

Answer (score 0):

`UIToolbar` contains instances of `UIBarButtonItem`, not `UIButton`.  If you just need a custom image, try:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(play:)];

// Build your array and setItems: using "item" among other objects

[item release];
```

Comment: need uibutton bcause need to add multiple actions

Comment: In that case, the easiest thing might be to simply have a wrapper method that merely invokes all the desired selectors.

Comment: issue is fixed. Thanks for help. though.