# iPhone sdk how to UIButton in UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

Is it possible to add an `UIButton` with `UIToolbar`? or we can use only `UIBarButtonItem`? If so how to add an `UIButton` in `UIToolbar`?

Comment: check it out ... may be it helps you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333441/adding-a-uilabel-to-a-uitoolbar

Comment: no that is for UILabel...and i knew it. How to add an UIButton with UIToolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:barBackButton]];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `UIBarButtonItem` to the `UIToolBar` like bellow..

This bellow is an example try this..

Just add this bellow code in viewDidLoad method and then see the `UIToolBar` with this two `UIBarButtonItems` also here i add Flixiblespace for set these two buttons with right and left corner of `UIToolBar`

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexiableItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];

UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, flexiableItem, item2, nil];   
self.toolbarItems = items;

[flexiableItem release];
[items release];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
```

Check this links for more information about [UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarButtonItem) and [UIToolbar_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**UPDATE:**

For your this requirement you can remove that buttons and also add new button instead of old .. see the example..

```
NSMutableArray     *items = [[yourToolbar.items mutableCopy] autorelease];
[items removeObject: yourButtons];
yourToolbar.items = items;
```

i hope this help you...

Comment: At present i used barbuttonitem only. But i want hide few buttons and add new buttons in certain conditions in the same position. Since we cannot hide BarButtonItem (Only we can enable/disable). I struck. Thats why am moving for UIButton.

Comment: @Saranya see the updated answer.. here you required to define buttons and tollbar globaly and just remove and add when you want like above .. hope now its useful to you.. :)

Comment: may be he wants the custom button only so he complete it dude.. :)