# UIButton in Toolbar ios

Tags: ios

It is possible to add **UIButton** with background programatically in the **toolbar**  and when I click on to the button it will display a uiActionSheet to let me take a picture from camera or from Photos Galery and when I select a picture it returns to the view and the background of the UIButton in toolbar change .

Comment: you should look to [UIBarButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Instead of it add UIButton in toolbar in xib. And change properties of it programmatically according to requirement.

Comment: What you have to tried ??? just search on google you will find lots of example to add button on toolbar and then search about UIAlertView and its delegate method you will get all of the feature which you need :) all the best :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251224/iphone-sdk-how-to-uibutton-in-uitoolbar

Comment: I think that i can't use UIBarButton if i want to change the background Image of the button , that's why i want to add a uibutton

Comment: U are telling about navigation bar, Right. Then U have to do using UIBarButton, then, be clear what U want to do with the button

Comment: U are telling about navigation bar, Right. Then U have to do using

Answer (score 0):

Create `UIBarButton` from `UIButton`:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableItem = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:toolbar.items];
UIBarButton *bookmark = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_m_bmBtn];
[mutableItem addObject:bookmark];
self.m_toolbarTop.items= mutableItem;
```

Hide / show another button:

1. `button.hidden = YES/ NO`.
2. Remove item in `mutableItem` and set: `self.m_toolbarTop.items= mutableItem;`