# How to Customize Toolbar inside a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a noob question.

I am developing a simple app that uses a navigation controller (so, a nav bar on top, and a toolbar is shown on bottom via interface builder; I use storyboards). This nav controller shows a number of related tables (table views) on different screens.

My question is: I want to populate the toolbars for each screen. Ideally, I'd like to populate a label there that shows a little summary text about the contents of the table view currently displayed - but I understand that that may not be the purpose of those toolbars, and not be supported by the UIKit toolbar view.
But what should work (to my modest understanding) is to show buttons there - individualized for the current screen. But I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to do that (I tried in interface builder - but on each screen controlled by the navigation controller, the toolbar is shown, but can not be accessed; it is also not referenced in the outline for that screen - only the outline for the navigation controller shows a reference to a toolbar, and if I change anything in it, which is possible, it does not show up in any of the screens controlled by the navigation controller).

Hope this is clear enough. I think this is a very simple issue to do - but I am stuck; Google searches didn't help me. Maybe someone of You can point me to some keywords to look for?

Thanks a lot for considering!

Best regards,
Björn

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to drag into the navigation controller bottom toolbar?

From my experience you are only allowed drag out Bar Button Item's along with Fixed and Flexible Spaces.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply! That's what I also figured out since. I tried to put a UILabel there - but it did not "stick" (toolbar rejected it - for lack of better terms to describe what happened in Storyboard; prob. You can clarify with a professional term).
I since found an article which gives a solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333441/adding-a-uilabel-to-a-uitoolbar) - unfortunately, I have not been able to reproduce in Xcode 7 beta (prob due to lack of skills on my side). So far, I alternatively change the title on a normal bar button item, but that's inflexible.